# Why is my jQuery animation pausing before it animates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Without posting 900 lines of javascript let me describe the situation. I built a webpage that works like an iphone app. You grab in the middle anywhere, swipe at least x-amount of pixels, let go, and it slides to the next page. This is triggering all sorts of events (including the ScrollTo plugin) and doing simple if-statements before executing.

My problem is, I am having a slight pause before the animated "slide to next page" occurs. Any clue what would cause this?

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, in how many different browsers have you tried this?

Comment: I almost wonder if the pause is getting longer, the more I use the web page, like something is stacking up.

Comment: do I need to apply .stop().animate to something?

Comment: do you have a url we can see?

Comment: .stop().animate is generally only used if you want to stop an animation before beginning a new one.  This is useful if you want to stop animations from stacking up.

Comment: If the pause is increasing, you have either a stacking animation delay, or a memory leak.

Comment: Optimizing your code is your best bet ('cache' your variables by performing as few selector lookups as possible, name functions where it makes sense, and try to be as clear as possible for the garbage collector). Without viewing the site/code it's hard to say anything exact though.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code [through jQuery Lint](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Lint) to see if it recommends any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using jQuery mobile, they are make things iPhone like.  It's also extremely fast and they will only improve the performance of it in the future.